# Remove the files in a folder which is present in s3 bucket while doing sync or copy operation from ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

In my ec2 instance I have 6 folders which are named like `test1, test2, test3, ..., test6`. In my s3 bucket I had 10 folders called `test1, ..., test10`. I want to sync only my local folders to s3 bucket folders.

Local folder in my ec2:

```
test1 : a.jpg,b.jpg
test2 : c.jpg,d.jpg
test3 : c.jpg,d.jpg
test4 : c.jpg,d.jpg
test5 : c.jpg,d.jpg
test6: e.jpg
```

But in my s3 bucket:

```
test1 : 1.jpg,2.jpg
test2 : 4.jpg,3.jpg
test3 : 5.jpg,6.jpg
test4 : 7.jpg,8.jpg
test5 : 9.jpg,10.jpg
test6 :  11.jpg
test7 : a.jpg,b.jpg
test8 : c.jpg,d.jpg
test9 : c.jpg,d.jpg
test10 : c.jpg,d.jpg
```

The folders contain different files. I want to replace these 6 folders' data in s3 bucket folders. How can I do this?

If I use `aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket/ --delete` ,I'm thinking it will delete the remaining folders in s3 bucket: `test7, test8, test9, test10`.
I want all the 10 folders in my s3 bucket, but only these 6 folders will have the same files which are present in the ec2 folders.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `aws s3 sync`? It says that you need to indicate the `--delete` option if you want files that exist in the destination but not in the source to be deleted during the sync. So, I think it would be quick to test the behavior here and decide if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following command:

```
aws s3 cp myDir s3://mybucket/ --recursive
```

This will copy all directories of `myDir` to S3.